# v440 battery replacement step by steps

Tags: solaris

I have such sever that requires battery replacement. I would like to know: how do I replace the battery?

This is a running server with important data on it, I would like to be extra careful.

```
Sun Fire v440
Solaris 8 2/04 s28s_hw4wos_05a SPARC
Copyright 2004 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Assembled 08 January 2004
```

Got this error on `prtdiag`:

> Battery faulty indicatior MB/BAT V_BAT 0.58V - 2.25V - - warning

How to get details on the battery part number? What are the steps?

Comment: *This is a running server with important data on it*  You have backups of that data, right?

Comment: yes we have backup of the data ready

Comment: This actually wasn't documented in the [service manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v440.srvr/816-7729-10/816-7729-10.pdf), so I don't think the downvotes are entirely appropriate...

Comment: Im getting the battery is it cr1632 or 2032..its diff size between two..dont wanna get the wrong ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a common CR1632 coin type battery which can be bought virtually anywhere in the world for a couple of dollars US. It keeps the system clock running whenever the system is powered off. What's surprising is that (1) it lasted this long, and (2) your company is still using that ancient server.

You replace it like any other such battery: pop the old one out and pop the new one in. Then be sure to reset the system clock, as it will most likely be wrong. But there's no need to hurry about this; you can do it whenever the system is next powered off for some other maintenance. Of course, given its extreme age, you should just decommission it before it blows up...

Comment: and use ESD wrist wrap?

Comment: That's always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks mate..its a relic machine..just maintaining its balanced life..now need to proceed on why system panic while tring to do sw mirror

Comment: *What's surprising is that (1) it lasted this long*  Not really.  Sun hardware was built like a battleship and lasts forever - especially the SPARC-based servers.  Many of them even came with a torque wrench inside the server - to properly replace CPUs should one go bad:  http://www.shrubbery.net/~heas/sun-feh-2_1/collections/fins/I0689-1.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle I meant the battery, not (entirely) the server!